DWT on STM32F411 running in debug mode but not release mode
Using the example code from this site (and all other examples appear to be similar):
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/01/30/cycle-counting-on-arm-cortex-m-with-dwt/
The DWT counter on the STM32F411 appears to increment correctly when running a debug session but not in a release session.  Here's an example function that uses DWT to execute a timeout on the I2C bus:
tKernelReturnValue 
OSp_I2C_Master_Send_Data(
    I2C_TypeDef * I2C, 
    char data) 
{
    uint32_t timeout = KIN1_DWT_CYCCNT;
    tKernelReturnValue result;
    
    I2C->DR = data;
    result.error = O$_I2C_TRANSMIT_ERROR;
    while(  (!(I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE)) &&
            ((KIN1_DWT_CYCCNT - timeout) < I2C_BUS_TIMEOUT) ) {
        OS_ClrWDT();
    } // end while
    if (I2C->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE) {
        result.error = O$_SUCCESS;
    } // end if
    return result;

} // end OSp_I2C_Master_Send_Data

In a live debug session I can verify the DWT is running, but the code won't break out of the while loop during a release build session.  Normally I would have assumed that a clock was incorrectly configured but the F411 reference manual doesn't indicate that the DWT connects to any clock source that has to be independently enabled.  I have used this same example code on the LPC55S69 and not had this issue.  I have also set the compiler to not optimize anything just in case.  Not sure what else to look at for this issue.

Did you enable DWT clock counter? Something like that (this is for f429 but that's the same arm core):
CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;
DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk;

Release vs debug build, means it's most likely some optimization. Verify that everything that needs to be volatile, is actually volatile. Missing volatile usually works in debug builds, because optimization if off. Maybe you could create a new empty project and try the DWT, make sure it works in debug and release builds there. You will be able to compare with your own working implementation then. To simplify debugging: create a separate variable which will contain (KIN1_DWT_CYCCNT - timeout), and compare against it in the while, you can observe the value then.
